# While converting from String to Object getting Typecast Error

Tags: java, string, object, casting

Following is the code which I am executing and getting error on line 14 as

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to TimeLimit

```
TimeLimit timeLimitValues = timeLimitValues(clientCompanyMarketMapId,
                productCatagory, productSubCatagory, supplierId);

String timeLimitValue = timeLimitValues.getTimeLimitValue();
String timeLimitTC = timeLimitValues.getTimeLimitTC();
timeLimitValues.getBookTravelDateTC();
String isPaymentEnabledFlag = timeLimitValues.getIsPaymentEnbld();
String isExpOnBkDate = timeLimitValues.getIsExponBkDate();
String timeExpiryDate = null;
TimeLimit expiryDate = new TimeLimit();

if (isPaymentEnabledFlag.equals("Y")) {
    if (isExpOnBkDate.equals("Y")) {
        if (timeLimitTC.equals("DAYS")) {
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, Integer.parseInt(timeLimitValue));
            timeExpiryDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
            expiryDate = timeExpiryDate;
            System.out.println("Expiry Date:   " + timeExpiryDate);

        }
```

Please help/guide

Comment: Can you provide stack trace?

Comment: expriyDate is of type TimeLimit and timeExpiryDate is of String hence getting the exception (3rd statement in innermost if statement).  What exactly you want to do?

Comment: converting string timeExpiryDate  to TimeLimit expiryDate  and then returning/setting it later on.

Comment: @Surmeet You should have some logic to convert the String timeExpiryDate ot TimeLimit instance expiryDate.  Where are you handling that?  You are simply assigning String to TimeLimit

Comment: @user3694267, tried that also, it didnt wrk...

Answer (score 2):

`timeExpiryDate` is declared in your code as a `String`.  `expiryDate` is declared as a `TimeLimit`.

You have the line

```
expiryDate = timeExpiryDate;
```

which will not even compile because you are trying to assign a `String` reference to a `TimeLimit` reference.

You need to write some sort of conversion method that takes a `String` and creates a `TimeLimit` from it.  It can be a utility method somewhere or it could be a `TimeLimit(String timeRepresentation)` constructor in the `TimeLimit` class.  Then for example you could write

```
expiryDate = new TimeLimit(timeExpiryDate);
```

or

```
expiryDate = SomeClass.convertToTimeLimit(timeExpiryDate);
```

Java is not like C++ (in case that's what you're used to).  Java will not automatically call a "conversion" constructor like C++ does.  So even if you have defined a `TimeLimit(String)` constructor, Java will not auto-call it to do the conversion.  You need to explicitly call it.

But in any event, there is no way to do the assignment without **you** writing some conversion method somewhere and then calling it.

Comment: Thanks for the help but don't wana change the POJO Class that I have made for TimeLimit..... Need some logic to convert String to TimeLimit Object in the Class that I had posted an example above.

Comment: Then write some method in some class that does the conversion and call it.